# Regular expression for search headline

Tags: regex, search, clojure

I am looking to use regular expressions to pick out a Yahoo search. Namely, I have searched Yahoo for `Clojure tutorial` and am looking to capture the word Clojure tutorial within

`https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=ApnVZAn6KsJdNlo0rRPgg4qbvZx4?p=clojure+tutorial&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-176`

I believe the function re-find will help me pick out my target, but am not sure how to formulate the regex. The problem is that the search result is not always positioned between ?p= and the ampersand &.

For instance a search for `clojure tutorial pdf` yields

`https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0LEVzoK3gtTQWAA.K5XNyoA;_ylc=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?gprid=NiWgEud.QceQh49qLkXBKA&pvid=fgnc0Tk4LjEqh.HYUvVT1Ad6MjQuNlML3gr_66io&p=clojure+tutorial+pdf&fr2=sa-gp&fr=yfp-t-176`

which traps the search &p= and an ampersand &.

In summary I am looking for a regular expression which captures searches that can take all character values and are found between either [? &]p=...&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:\?|\&)p=(.+?)\&
```

Free spaced:

```
(?:\?|\&)   //A literal question mark OR ampersand
p=          //Followed by "p="
(.+?)       //Followed by at-least one of [anything but an ampersand]
\&          //Followed by an ampersand.
```

Capture group $1 contains the search-term

The `.+?` is non-greedy, so it will go up to the *next* ampersand. If you changed it to `.+`--which is not what you want to do--it would be greedy and capture everything through the *last* ampersand in the string.

An alternative that would work is:

```
(?:\?|\&)p=([^&]+)
```